# Passar informação para um Modal do Bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap-3, modal

Preciso passar o `id` de um modal para o meu `controller.php`. No modal, ao clicar no botão "excluir" eu estou tentando passar via `POST` o `id` do cliente, mas o controller não recebe nada.

Aqui eu pego os dados que estão no banco:

```
foreach($dados as $row){
    $idCliente   = $row['idClienteFisico'];
    $nomeCliente = $row['nomeCliente'];
    $rgCliente   = $row['rgCliente'];
    $cpfCliente  = $row['cpfCliente'];
}
```

Aqui é o botão que ativa o modal e passa para o jQuery o `id` e nome pelo `data-id` e pelo `data-nome`.

```
<button type="button" data-id="<?php echo $idCliente; ?>" data-nome="<?php echo $nomeCliente; ?>" data-remote="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" class="btn btn-danger"><em class="fa fa-trash"></em></button>
```

Aqui é o meu Modal do Bootstrap onde eu recebo o `id` e o nome do cliente

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Excluir Cliente</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="../Controller/cadastro.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <h3>Deseja excluir</h3>
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">ID:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control hidden" id="recipient-name" name="id">
          </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="btnDelete" name="btnDelete">Excluir</button>
      </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aqui é onde eu abro o modal e por onde eu passo o id e o nome do cliente pelo "data-id" e "data-nome" do meu button.

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
    var id = button.data('id') 
    var nome = button.data('nome')

    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(id)
    modal.find('.modal-body h3').text('Deseja excluir o usuario ' +nome+ '?')
})
```

O meu controller.php está assim:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnDelete'])){
    $dao = new funcionarioDAO();
    $dao->Deletar($_GET['id']);
}
```

Do jeito que esta aí eu estou recebendo o `id` e o nome no modal. Mas não sei como enviar o `id` via `POST` para o meu `controller.php` que irá receber o `id` e deletar o Cliente.

Alguma Sugestão?

Comment: vc quer enviar o ID para o input do MODAL e do MODAL para o controller.php? É isso?

Comment: Você está enviando o form via post e recuperando o id via get no PHP. mude a linha: `$dao->Deletar($_GET['id']);` para: `$dao->Deletar($_POST['id']);`.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, montei esse script vê se te ajuda; ao clicar no botão "Excluir" da modal, você carrega a pagina controle dentro da própria modal, passando os dados via $_POST, assim os dados serão excluidos!

```
<script>
    $("#btnDelete").click(function(){
        var id = button.data('id'); //recuperando id
        $("#retorno").load("controller.php", {id:id}); //carregando pagina controller.php passando id por POST
    }); 
</script>   

<html>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="btnDelete" name="btnDelete" id="btnDelete">Excluir</button>
    <div id="retorno" style="display:none"></div> <!--Div onde vai carregar a controller.php -->    
</html>
```

Só utilizei o trecho do botão da modal neste exemplo!

Comment: Boa noite, Paul. Obrigado pela ajuda, mas não funcionou. Meu controller continua sem receber nenhum dado. Será que tem alguma outra forma? Será que tem alguma forma de passar o id do modal para o Controller.php através do Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Seu código, **com algumas alterações**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
        send_data();
    });
});

function send_data(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../Controller/cadastro.php",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id:$("#recipient-name").val()
        },
        success: function () {
            alert('Enviou o ID '+$("#recipient-name").val()+"!");
            // Fecha o MODAL
            //$('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Falhou ao enviar o ID '+$("#recipient-name").val()+"!");
        }
    });
}
</script>

<button type="button" data-id="<?php echo $idCliente; ?>" data-nome="<?php echo $nomeCliente; ?>" data-remote="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" class="btn btn-danger">
    <em class="fa fa-trash"></em>
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Excluir Cliente</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="../Controller/cadastro.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h3>Deseja excluir</h3>
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">ID: <?php echo $idCliente; ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control hidden" id="recipient-name" name="id" value="<?php echo $idCliente; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="btnDelete" name="btnDelete" id="btnDelete">Excluir</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**OBS:** quando for trabalhar com JQuery, use id, é mais prático para referenciar os elementos. Já que vc não precisa enviar todos os dados do FORM, não precisa do SUBMIT. O POST é feito pela função send_data().